# Which r s-squared score is more helpful?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-regression

```
   data.drop('Movie Title', axis=1, inplace=True)
   features = data.loc[:, data.columns != 'worldwide_gross_usd']
   charges = data['worldwide_gross_usd']

   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, 
                                                        charges, 
                                                        random_state=42, 
                                                        test_size = 0.2)
    
    regr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)
    
    print('Trained R-squared score: ', regr.score(X_train, y_train))
    print('Tested R-squared score: ', regr.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Output:

> Trained R-squared score:  0.5404764241697003

> Tested R-squaredscore:  0.5845801856343114

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, 
                                                    charges, 
                                                    random_state=12, 
                                                    test_size = 0.2)

regr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)

print('Trained R-squared score: ', regr.score(X_train, y_train))
print('Tested R-squared score: ', regr.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Output:

> Trained R-squared score:  0.5345435646372121

> Tested R-squaredscore:  0.602138324770633

As you can notice when I changed the `random_state` value, my training score decreased by 1% but my testing score increased by 2%
Which R-squared score would you rather go with the first or the second?

Comment: Kindly avoid using bold for whole paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**R-squared scored is a quick estimate for regression model, but not a good estimator.**

> It is like:
>
> You have 3 points on a 2D plane (say p1, p2, p3).
>
> In 1st case, you plot regression line using p1 and p2, then test it on
> p3, and get r1 scores.
>
> Nextly, you plot regression line using p2 and p3, then test it on p1,
> and get r2 scores.
>
> So, you cannot fully depend on just R-squared score with different random state.

**Inferences:**

1. If all of your data points are equally relevant, then the higher R-squared score on test set is better.
2. If you are not sure about relevance of your dataset, then you should check on **other parameters/method** to find which R-squared score is better.

**Other parameters/methods:**

You should plot residual plots for both the cases. Check which one has mean close to zero and variance close to 1 (for most of the datasets), that one is better. If the residual plot in any of the cases has some pattern in it, then that case is not good and can be improved. If the residual plot in any of the cases has residuals in it, then that case is also not good and can be improved.

> Note: For example, you want to predict house prices, and have data of
> area of house, location, BHK, number of people previously living
> there, etc. But house prices depends more on area of house rather
> number of people previously living there. So both are not equally
> relevant. This is what I mean by equally relevant.